# Purge snapd does not delete package files

Tags: apt, snap, purge

I removed `snapd` from my computer by following the instructions at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2328152:

```
sudo apt purge snapd ubuntu-core-launcher squashfs-tools
```

However, my system is still full of files and directories that are related (I think) to the `snapd` package, as you can see from the result of `locate snapd`.

I have 2 questions:

1. Why didn't `apt purge` get rid of all these files?
2. Is it safe to remove them, or are some of these being used by the system or by some other package? If so, how can I find out?

   `/etc/apparmor.d/snap.core.3887.usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine
   /etc/apparmor.d/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real 
   /etc/apparmor.d/cache/snap.core.3887.usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine 
   /etc/apparmor.d/cache/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real
   /etc/apparmor.d/local/usr.lib.snapd.snap-confine.real
   /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.autoimport.service 
   /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.core-fixup.service 
   /etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.service 
   /etc/systemd/system/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket 
   /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/snapd.refresh.timer 
   /etc/systemd/system/timers.target.wants/snapd.snap-repair.timer 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.autoimport.service 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.core-fixup.service 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.service 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.refresh.timer 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.service /lib/systemd/system/snapd.snap-repair.service /lib/systemd/system/snapd.snap-repair.timer 
   /lib/systemd/system/snapd.socket /lib/systemd/system/snapd.system-shutdown.service /lib/udev/rules.d/66-snapd-autoimport.rules 
   /usr/lib/snapd /usr/lib/snapd-glib 
   /usr/lib/snapd-glib/snapd-login-service 
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnapd-glib.so.1 
   /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsnapd-glib.so.1.0.0 
   /usr/share/doc/libsnapd-glib1 
   /usr/share/doc/snapd 
   /usr/share/doc/snapd-login-service 
   /usr/share/doc/libsnapd-glib1/changelog.Debian.gz 
   /usr/share/doc/libsnapd-glib1/copyright 
   /usr/share/doc/snapd-login-service/changelog.Debian.gz
   /usr/share/doc/snapd-login-service/copyright 
   /usr/share/polkit-1/actions/io.snapcraft.snapd.policy 
   /var/cache/snapd /var/cache/apt/archives/snapd_2.29.4.2_amd64.deb 
   /var/lib/snapd 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib1:amd64.list 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib1:amd64.md5sums 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib1:amd64.shlibs 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib1:amd64.symbols
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/libsnapd-glib1:amd64.triggers 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd-login-service.conffiles 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd-login-service.list 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd-login-service.md5sums 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.conffiles 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.list 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.md5sums 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.postinst 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.postrm 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.preinst 
   /var/lib/dpkg/info/snapd.prerm 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.autoimport.service.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.core-fixup.service.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.refresh.timer.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.service.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.snap-repair.timer.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.socket.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/snapd.system-shutdown.service.dsh-also 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.autoimport.service 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.core-fixup.service 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/multi-user.target.wants/snapd.service 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/sockets.target.wants/snapd.socket 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/timers.target.wants/snapd.refresh.timer 
   /var/lib/systemd/deb-systemd-helper-enabled/timers.target.wants/snapd.snap-repair.timer 
   /var/lib/systemd/timers/stamp-snapd.refresh.timer`

Answer (score 1):

The packaging system (dpkg) does not remove dfiles created outside of the packaging system, generally. Most of the files you're referencing here were generated when installing snaps on your system. However, it appears you do still have the `snapd` package installed, along with `libsnapd-glib1` and `snapd-login-service`.

Try `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge libsnapd-glib1 snapd` to remove them.